Real time Cursor tracking in Autodesk Viewer
I am trying to setup real-time cursor tracking in Autodesk Viewer. Sometimes, there is distance between the cursor and the mesh. When I rotate the project (building model, in my case), the mesh disappears or moves in the wrong direction.
The following is the script I am using:
const geom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(10, 10, 10);
        const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 });
        const sphereMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, material);
        sphereMesh.position.set(Math.random() * 100 - 50, Math.random() * 100 - 50, 0);
        const customSceneIdentifier = 'custom-scene';

        if (!viewer.overlays.hasScene(customSceneIdentifier)) {
            viewer.overlays.addScene(customSceneIdentifier);
        }
        viewer.overlays.addMesh(sphereMesh, customSceneIdentifier);
        viewer.container.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
            const camera = viewer.navigation.getCamera();
            const vec = new THREE.Vector3();
            const pos = new THREE.Vector3();

            vec.set(
                (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1,
                -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1,
                0.5
            );

            vec.unproject(camera);
            vec.sub(camera.position).normalize();

            const distance = -camera.position.z / vec.z;
            pos.copy(camera.position).add(vec.multiplyScalar(distance));
            sphereMesh.position.copy(pos);
            viewer.impl.invalidate(true, true, true);
        });


Isn't this what you are trying to do, checking what 3D point of the model the cursor is hitting?
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/drag-and-drop-models-viewer
So you can use viewer.impl.hitTest to check if the cursor hits an object on the model, otherwise use viewer.impl.intersectGround to check what the 3D position on the ground the cursor corresponds to.

It's not accurate in the sense that it shows where on the floor/model's ground the cursor is when it is zoomed out. I want the mesh to be visually at the position of cursor. With hitTest and intersectGround implementation, It only happens when I am sufficiently zoomed in.

This seems to work - the relevant part:
function startEventListener() {
  const geom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(10, 10, 10);
  const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 });
  const sphereMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, material);
  sphereMesh.position.set(
    Math.random() * 100 - 50,
    Math.random() * 100 - 50,
    0
  );
  const customSceneIdentifier = "custom-scene";

  if (!viewer.overlays.hasScene(customSceneIdentifier)) {
    viewer.overlays.addScene(customSceneIdentifier);
  }
  viewer.overlays.addMesh(sphereMesh, customSceneIdentifier);
  viewer.container.addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) {
    
    const camera = viewer.navigation.getCamera();
    const pos = new THREE.Vector3();
  
    pos.set(
      (event.canvasX / viewer.container.clientWidth) * 2 - 1,
      -(event.canvasY / viewer.container.clientHeight) * 2 + 1,
      0.5
    );
    pos.unproject(camera);   

    sphereMesh.position.copy(pos);
    
    viewer.impl.invalidate(true, true, true);
  });
}

See https://youtu.be/VzNH_dCbBOg
The full html page that you can open with an HTTP server:
https://github.com/adamenagy/Container/blob/master/fusion-test-3Dcursor.html
